# angular ng update not working - timeout where proxy is saved?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have an issue with my angular project
when im ad towk i use proxy when im home i use no proxy
so i add

```
 npm config set https-proxy http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9090
 npm config set proxy http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9090
```

and it works 
at home usually

```
 set HTTP_PROXY=
 npm config rm proxy
 npm config rm https-proxy
 npm config rm http-proxy
```

but not now - i deleted proxy cause im home
but when i run ng update i get 
`An unhandled exception occurred: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:9090`

when i do npm update - it works fine
when i deleted `nodemodules` - and then do `npm install` - it works fine

when i in some other folder do `ng new`.... and then `ng update` - it WORKS

it does not work ONLY in this one project - is this proxy saved elsewhere ? in project folder maybe? i searched a lot but did not found

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so after a while....
when i rename this folder with project - still no change / not works !!
but when i did select all > copy > and pasted to other folder
ALL WITH HIDDEN FILES .git folder etc 
it works.
so no idea where it is holding that 
i searched regedit also - nothing...

if anyone known please let me known ;)
regards

edit
FINALY I KNOWN

i have 2 HDD in this laptop
one with work system and 
second with home system

so the problem was on home system lets call that this is C: drive
work system is E: drive

the project was at E:\Users\d00lar\Desktop,
"npm config list" retuns that it was using C:\Users\d00lar.npmrc config
BUT THIS IS LIE !!!!
it was using 
E:\Users\d00lar.npmrc !!! and there was this proxy configuration !!

so when i copied this folder from E: to c: then it 
start using C:\Users\d00lar.npmrc config and thats why after copy/paste it worked but only if i copied to other then E drive !

but on E drive even if system was running from C it was using this E: .npmrc  file whth proxy config and that was this %$#$& problem ;)

regards future searchers - enjoy - it took me about 8h ;/ ;p

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an .npmrc file in your project that contains the proxy configuration for you. You have to remove the proxy configuration in the .npmrc file.

Comment: where ? in root ? i searched in folder *.npmrc but not found any file.... i also searched in this folder for this xx.xx.xx.xx:9090 and marked 'search inside of files' not found also ;/

Comment: Yes, it should be in the root of the project. Could you please try to run "npm config list" command from the root of the project? Do you see the proxy configuration in the output of the command?

Comment: only proxy=null in .npmrc file as you told but in c/users/

; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.12.0 node/v12.13.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\d00lar\.npmrc
proxy = null

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\d00lar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = E:\Users\d00lar\Desktop\_work_\Dev\angular\seais21
; HOME = C:\Users\d00lar
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.